# Data-Dismiss: How to dismiss bootstrap modal inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal in which I need to validate some input using knockout validation.
When I click the submit button, a function is called that validates the data. The following functionality is expected:

- If the validation fails, the modal stays open and the validation reason is displayed.
- If the validation succeeds, I want to close the modal.

How can I go about closing the modal inside my function?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? It should be pretty straight forward, normally Bootstrap and other jQuery based packages have a 'close' method you can call on the element

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What have you tried so far?

Per the Bootstrap documentation

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

Please read through the documentation!

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I was under the impression that data-dismiss and hide were different. Your solution worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The above didn't work for me, modified slightly to add an id to the button and reference it that way.  I just used the cancel button that was already on my modal form and added id="cancel-btn" to that one.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-ar btn-default" id="cancel-btn" data-dismiss="modal">  

$('#cancel-btn').click();
```

Answer (score 5):

Make another button like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg shiny" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
```

This button contains data-dismiss="modal" .You can hide this button if you want.

Now You can use any other function in a customized way and when you want to hide the modal you can call

```
$(".btn-warning").click();
```

Answer (score 3):

This will only hide modal

```
$('#modalId').modal('hide');
```

but other modal related stuff will not remove.

To completely remove modal from page and its css

```
$('#modalId').modal('hide'); or $('#modalId').modal('toggle');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('body').css('padding-right', '0px');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Here I'm giving a solution in plain javascript. I used Vue js and I don't want to use jQuery along with Vue.



document.querySelector('#modalid').classList.remove('show');
  document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('modal-open');
  const mdbackdrop = document.querySelector('.modal-backdrop');
  if (mdbackdrop){
    mdbackdrop.classList.remove('modal-backdrop', 'show');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here´s the Answer for BS5:

You initialize the Modal like it is descripted [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#via-javascript)

```
let myModal = new bootsrap.Modal('#myModalId', {})
```

Now you can just hide it over a simple function.

```
myModal.hide()
```